# Copying exact position and pointing angles of a tracked camera with non-tracked camera

Tags: camera

working on a 900 frame animation. camera 1 is constrained / tracked to an empty, but at frame 700 i want the camera to move freely for the final 200 frames. i copied camera 1 at frame 700. camera 2 is in perfect alignment with camera 1 until i remove the constraint. camera 2 then shifts (same vector but pointing a different way) and its hard to line up again. am i missing something? is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Switching from a constrained cam (track to) to a duplicate and maintaining the exact same view as the original cam when the constraint is removed from the duplicate -

Take the timeline cursor to the switch over frame.

Duplicate the camera.

The duplicated cam will inherit the same constraint as the first.  To prevent it swinging back when the constraint is removed, select the duplicate cam and press "CTL-A --> Visual Transform".

Then delete the constraint from the duplicate.

When switched to the duplicate, the cam view should remain exactly as the original cam was.

Comment: thank you very much, Edgel3D. worked perfectly. I owe you a drink! if you're ever in Vancouver, BC...

Comment: Glad to hear that, no probs mate!