# How to Delete Camera "Track To" Constraint, But Keep Transformation Settings?

Tags: camera, constraints

I have the camera tracking an object with a "Track To" Constraint.  After the camera is done tracking the object I want it to continue, but I want to delete the constraint at a certain keyframe and keep the camera set to the exact same coordinates.

When I delete the constraint the camera jumps back to it's state before the constraint was added.  How do I get around this?

In other words: Can you apply a Constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an Influence parameter in camera Track To constraint.

You can use a copy location constraing as explained in this post [Camera follow object and then stop in place](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108751/115475)

Comment: Thank you!  This works.  But I will say that considering the "Apply" functionality that Modifiers use, it would be a lot less confusing if there was an Apply function for the Constraints as well.  I may put this in the suggestion bin ;)